# Querying JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to query a JArray where having b2b_pid = 1 using code below, but keeps failing

any body can help?

```
        JArray _ja = new JArray();

        object _o = new
        {
            b2b_pid = 1,
            a_pid = 2
        };

        _ja.Add(JObject.FromObject(_o));

        _o = new
        {
            b2b_pid = 1,
            a_pid = 3
        };

        _ja.Add(JObject.FromObject(_o));

        _o = new
        {
            b2b_pid = 2,
            a_pid = 33
        };

        _ja.Add(JObject.FromObject(_o));

        JArray _mja = (JArray)_ja.Children<JObject>().Where(o => (long)o["b2b_pid"] == 1);
```

**thrown me an exception:**

**Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray**

Comment: `but keeps failing` what does it mean? What exactly happens? What issue you are facing?

Comment: sorry, I meant I am unable to get the result of _mja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the filtered items to [`JArray` constructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_3.htm) directly

```cs
var _mja = new JArray(_ja.Children<JObject>().Where(o => o["b2b_pid"].Value<long>() == 1));
```

Your error message is pretty clear and tells that you can't cast the `Where` result to `JArray` directly. Also, to get a specific value of `b2b_pid` you can use [`Value<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) method